# Riesz representation for the dual

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Prove the lemma:

> If E be a measurable set.and $1\le p <\infty$ and g is integrable over E there is a $M\ge 0$ for which $|\int_Egf|\le M\|f\|_p$ for every simple function $f$ in $L^p(E)$   then g belongs to $L^q(E)$ where $q$ is conjugate of p with $\|g\|_q\le M$

The idea is first approximate $|g|$ with $ 0\le\psi_n\le |g|$ by sequence of simple function ,
It suffices to prove that $\int_E\psi^q_n(x) \le M^q $ for all $n$.

To do this we first make it like the bound $|\int_Egf|\le M\|f\|_p$,that is let $f_n = \text{sgn}(g)\psi^{q-1}_n(x)$ as the $f$ in the bound.

But the question here is Why $f_n \in L^p(E)$?

This is the lemma in Royden fourth edition page 158

Comment: Simple function may not be integrable ?The book says that it has finite support hence belong to $L^p(E)$.Why it has finite support ?Since simple function approximation theorem does not state it

Comment: I get it, thanks for your help.

Comment: I converted my comments to an answer so that this question can get marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $f_n$ is a simple function also. Since a simple function is integrable if and only if its support has finite measure, it will suffice to show that $\operatorname{supp}f_n$ has finite measure. However, it is clear that $\operatorname{supp}f_n = \operatorname{supp}{\psi_n}$ and since $0 \leq \psi_n \leq |g|$ with $g$ integrable we have that $\psi_n$ is integrable so that its support has finite measure. This proves the desired result.